# Sound isn't working in Super Meat Boy (native 64bit)

Tags: sound, games

I have been having problems getting sound to work in Super Meat Boy from the latest Humble Indie Bundle. No error messages, just no sound. Volumes are turned up.

This is the 64bit native build, ***not*** the Windows version running through Wine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The included `libopenal` binary is dodgy. I fixed the sound by replacing it with a link to the Ubuntu version like so:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/games/supermeatboy/amd64/libopenal.so.1{,BAK}
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libopenal.so /usr/local/games/supermeatboy/amd64/libopenal.so.1
```

And that's that. Working sound.

This assumes you downloaded the deb and installed it. If you downloaded the tar or have done this another method, you can still do the above but you'll need to edit the paths to point to your installation. Or go and get the deb.